# Integer solutions to $x^2+1=ay$

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

I'd like to know if there is a formula for finding integer solutions to equations of the form
$$x^{2}+1=ay$$
where $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $x$ and $y$ are unknowns.

Comment: Perhaps including what you've tried/context would be helpful.

Comment: X=any odd number , y=2 will give an integer a always , have I understood your problem correctly??@Krypto14

Comment: @AtulMishra $a$ is a given constant and we are solving for $(x,y)$

Comment: For any prime $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we can solve $x^2+1\equiv 0 \pmod p$,  which gives you infinitely many solutions.  Of course, even in that case it is hard to write them down explicitly.

Comment: If you are interested in this kind of problems maybe you can to read a consequence of the abc conjecture for a different diophantine equation (the satement of the abc conjecture also is explained in the article): Florian Luca, *THE DIOPHANTINE EQUATION* $P(x)=n!$ *AND A RESULT OF M. OVERHOLT*, Glasnik Matematicki, Vol. 37, No.2 (2002), [here](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/glasnik/vol_37/no2_04.html) you've free access, from the Department of Mathematics of University of Zagreb (Croatia), see [here](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/glasnik/). Is not required a response of this message, good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is equvalent to solving
$$
x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod a
$$
That is a well-known problem; look up Quadratic Residues on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue for example.  The punch line is that if $a$ is prime or if you can factor $a$, the problem is fairly easy; if
$a$ is composite and so large that you cannot factor it, the problem is very hard.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need $a \ne 0$.  You need $x$ to be a square root of $-1 \mod a$, and then $y = (x^2+1)/a$.  For $-1$ to have a square root $\mod a$, you need $a$ to be either odd or $2$ times an odd number,
and to have no prime factors $\equiv 3 \mod 4$.  Then if $a$ has $k$ distinct odd prime factors, there are $2^k$ possible values for $x \mod a$.